# Azure pipeline make nuget package

Tags: azure-pipelines

Three questions:

- how to set the package version,
- why does it think that the package alrady exists when it does not, and
- the value of `publishVstsFeed`.

I would like the package version to be:

```
<VersionPrefixFromCsproj>.BuildId-branchNameIfNotMaster
```

This sort of seems to be working

csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>MyDll</RootNamespace>
    <Title>MyDll</Title>
    <Authors>Me/Authors>
    <Description>MyDll</Description>
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.0</VersionPrefix>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\$(TargetFramework)\$(AssemblyName).xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

`azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    tag: ''
    
  ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
    tag: ${{ format('-{0}', variables['Build.SourceBranchName']) }}

...
# this seems to be working -- don't know which input makes the version number happen
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack MyDll'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: 'MyDll/PMyDll.csproj'
    includesymbols: true
    includesource: true
    nobuild: true
    buildProperties: 'VersionSuffix="$(Build.BuildId)$(tag)"'
    versionSuffix: '$(Build.BuildId)$(tag)'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    arguments: '--version-suffix $(Build.BuildId)$(tag)'

# This fails:
# Response status code does not indicate success: 
# 409 (Conflict - The feed already contains 'MyDll 1.0.0-10161-pqckage-yml'.
# This is not true. Version 1.0.0 already exists but not 1.0.0-10161-pqckage-yml
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'dotnet push *.nupkg'
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'    
    publishVstsFeed: 'Some-DLLs' # How do you work out what to put here?
    #publishVstsFeed: '/c75f4487-7dd4-4e5a-8b50-0e6707ed5402'
    #publishVstsFeed: '/tfs-project/Some-DLLs'
```

**Update**

It seems that the package *does* get pushed, but then the stupid task tries to push it again and again. Is it a bug in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

`**/*.nupkg` matches more than one file -- there's also a `.symbols.nupkg` -- so a `push` is run for each. Therefore the fix is

```
packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*symbols.nupkg'
```

I wanted to prove this by lissint all `*.nupkg` files for which this works in a PowerShell window, but of coure it doesn't work in a pipeline because nothing ever bloody does.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'ls *.nupkg'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Get-ChildItem *.nupkg -Recurse'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.